Отображение данных из Localstorage в HTML
То что написано в JS:
let cart = document.getElementById('cart');
let cartData = localStorage.getItem('cart');

if (cart == null){
    cart.innerHTML;
}
else{
    cart.innerHTML = cartData;
}

То что написано в Html:
<div id='cart' class = 'block_basket'> </div>

То что было в JS при получении данных:
var buyButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.buyButton');

    buyButtons.forEach(function (buyButton) {
        buyButton.addEventListener('click', function () {

            var productContainer = this.parentNode;
            var productName = productContainer.querySelector('.name_product').innerText;
            var productPrice = productContainer.querySelector('.price_product').innerText;
            var productImage = productContainer.querySelector('.image_product').getAttribute('src');

            var productData = {
                name: productName,
                price: productPrice,
                image: productImage
            };

            var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
            cart.push(productData);
            localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));

Делаю это на Django все файлы друг с другом связаны уже проверял но данные не выводятся(сами данные успешно сохраняются смотрел через консоль разработчика)

Когда срабатывет первая часть скрипта и когда вторая?

Последний код прописан для products.html по нажатии кнопки у товара сохраняются данные(он на эту страницу и подключен); пользователь переходит в корзину(basket.html) там уже подключен файл с 1 кодом если я правильно понял вопрос.

if (cart == null) { cart.innerHTML; } — что это за ватафак?  При выполнении этого условия, на доступе к свойству innerHTML у тебя скрипт просто обвалится с исключением... Замени это на if (cart == null) { console.error('АЛЯРМ!'); } и посмотри что в консоли браузера происходит (если "алярм" выведется, значит элемент отсутствует в момент выполнения скрипта).

Короче я нашел проблему но все равно спасибо
